# Difference Between AccountId and UserId in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, stack-exchange

I ran SQL query in Stack Exchange,

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    Id=4453737
ORDER BY
    Reputation DESC;
```

I got some fields in it including **AccountId**
I know UserId is our unique ID then what about AccountId?

what is the difference between Both?

Comment: One *major* difference to be aware of is that `UserID` isn't unique. Any number of users can use the same `UserId `, which allows at best for confusion, or, worse, forgery and identity theft.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`AccountId` is the id that belongs to [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5463752/mohideen-ibn-mohammed). So it is a ForeignKey to the `Account` table. However, that table isn't in SEDE.

It is stable across all your user profiles on all sites.

[**`UserId`**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4453737/mohideen-ibn-mohammed) is per site (and different per site)

You can do some nice cross-site analysis with `UserId` and `Accountid` like I did for [Who is the user with highest combined reputation from all Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279137/158100)

You can find the tables, attributes and their meaning in [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Comment: +1 for the link to the interesting query about the "highest combined reputation"

Comment: Which one do you use to join into for example Badges.UserId?

Comment: @rjurney the `Id`  of the `Users` table.